# What make my C++ ctime - related functions behave weirdly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, epoch, ctime

I made two functions that are to calculate beginning timestamp of the day (i.e. at 00:00:00 of the day) and the hour (starting from 1 and up to 24) of a given epoch timestamp.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>

const uint8_t FIRST_HOUR = 0x01;  // 01, 02, ..., 24
const uint32_t SECS_PER_HOUR = 3600;  // 3600 secs per hour

uint32_t CalcDaiBaseTimestamp(uint32_t in_ts) {
  time_t ts = in_ts;
  struct tm timeinfo = *localtime(&ts);
  timeinfo.tm_hour = 0;
  timeinfo.tm_min = 0;
  timeinfo.tm_sec = 0;
  time_t tmp_base_ts = mktime(&timeinfo);

  return (uint32_t)tmp_base_ts;
}

void CalcDaiBaseTimestampAndHour(uint32_t in_ts,
                                 uint32_t& base_ts,
                                 uint8_t& hour_nth) {
  base_ts = CalcDaiBaseTimestamp(in_ts);
  hour_nth = (in_ts - base_ts) / SECS_PER_HOUR + FIRST_HOUR;
}
```

`CalcDaiBaseTimestampAndHour` is invoked from multiple threads.

The code is compiled with `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4` and the program runs on `Ubuntu 14.04 x64`.

Most of time my program works well, but I have sometimes observed some "weird" result as shown below:

```
(timestamp: 1554459477.500) -> (base: 1553990400, hour_nth: 131)
```

While the correct result should be:

```
(timestamp: 1554459477.500) -> (base: 1554422400 / hour_nth: 11)
```

Because:

```
1554459477.500 = 2019-04-05 10:17:57.500
base_ts = 2019-04-05 00:00:00 = 1554422400
hour_nth = 11
```

Since the issue happens sometimes so I would suppose that the reason could be thread-safety of some `ctime` - related functions.

What could cause the "weird" results? Please help me troubleshoot this! If the reason is actually thread-safety of the `ctime` - related functions then how could I work around this (with some C++ 11 standard library e.g.)?

Comment: `std::localtime` may not be thread safe (it is in some implementations). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The future c++20 date library might help you do this more easily/safely https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: @AlanBirtles The code is compiled with g++ 4.8.4 with C++11 standard enabled.

Comment: The date library is compatible with c++11

Comment: @AlanBirtles Could you please show me how to work around this using the date library?

Comment: read the documentation or just use the threadsafe `localtime_r`

Answer (score 3):

> Could you please show me how to work around this using the date library?

Reference link:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Code:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    using dsec = duration<double>;
    sys_time<dsec> tp{dsec{1554459477.500}};
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed
              << tp.time_since_epoch().count()
              << " = " << round<milliseconds>(tp) << '\n';
    sys_seconds base_ts = floor<days>(tp);
    std::cout << "base_ts = " << base_ts << " = "
              << base_ts.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
    auto hour_nth = floor<hours>(tp - base_ts) + hours{1};
    std::cout << "hour_nth = " << hour_nth.count() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1554459477.500 = 2019-04-05 10:17:57.500
base_ts = 2019-04-05 00:00:00 = 1554422400
hour_nth = 11
```

Notes:

- There exist no thread safety issues here.
- As long as you don't need time zone support, "date/date.h" is a single-header, header-only library.
- Everything above is UTC.
- Documentation:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html